# Pass click event id to another component in react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have one react component 'A' which has a table and each row has a button and on click of that button we need to get id of each row and that id is to be passed to another component 'B'.

I have used redux store to have the data.

My code is :

Tablelist.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link , Route, Switch ,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {upcoming_holiday_details} from '../actions/index.jsx'
import {upcoming_holiday_detail_reducer} from '../reducers/upcomingholidaydetails.jsx'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class UpcomingHolidays extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { Upcoming_HolidayList: [] };
        this.handleclick =this.handleclick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
         this.props.upcoming_holiday_details();
         this.setState({Upcoming_HolidayList:this.props.upcoming_holiday_details()})
    }

    handleclick:function()
    {
        this.props.details_holidays(this.props.Upcoming_HolidayList.upcomingholidaylist_data.id);
        console.log('generate deta based on holidayssssssss',this.props.Upcoming_HolidayList.upcomingholidaylist_data.id)
        return false;
    }

    render()
    {
    /* The data from reducer is objects of objects type and so the conversion into array of objects an dpassing into
     components  for processing.
      */
            const rows = this.props.Upcoming_HolidayList.upcomingholidaylist_data;
            var arr_list=[];
            for (var key in rows) {
                rows[key].hdate = rows[key].start_date.split('-').splice(2);
                var month_split = rows[key].start_date.split('-').splice(1);
                rows[key].hmonth = month_split[0];
                arr_list.push(rows[key])
            }
    /* based on the response from store is empty or not and we test it  on if statement the response template changes */
            let  userMessage;
            if (rows[key].id!="" && rows[key].name!="" && rows[key].start_date!="" && rows[key].end_date!="" && rows[key].description!="" )
            {
                userMessage =(
                    <div className="panel-body event">
                        {arr_list && arr_list.map((holiday) => {
                        return <div className="notice-calendar-list clearfix">
                                    <div className="notice-calendar">
                                        <span className="month">{holiday.hmonth}</span>
                                        <span className="date">{holiday.hdate}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="notice-calendar-heading">
                                        <h5 className="notice-calendar-heading-title">
                                            <Link to='/userdashboard/eventdetails'>{holiday.name}</Link>
                                        </h5>
                                        <div className="notice-calendar-date"><span className="text-danger">End Date: </span>
                                            {holiday.end_date}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="calendarview">
                                        <span className="pull-right">
                                            <strong>**<Link to='/userdashboard/eventdetails' params={click_id:holiday.id} className="calendardetails" onClick={this.handleClick}>View Details</Link>**</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        })}
                    </div>

                )

            }
            else
            {
                userMessage =(
                    <div className="panel-body event">
                        <h6> Sorry!!!There are no UpcomingHolidays in this month !!!</h6>
                    </div>

                )
            }

        /* Based on the conditional check,the userMessage value inside the component is rendered */
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-info">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h2 className="panel-title"><i className="fa fa-binoculars"></i><strong> Upcoming Holidays</strong><span className="pull-right"><Link to='/userdashboard/holidayslist' className=" view-all-front">View All</Link></span></h2>
                </div>
                {userMessage}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state,props) {
    console.log(state,'state listt')
  return {
    Upcoming_HolidayList: state
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    upcoming_holiday_details: upcoming_holiday_details}, dispatch);
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UpcomingHolidays);
```

Tableitemviewdetails.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Link , Route, Switch ,browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {upcoming_holiday_details} from '../actions/index.jsx'
import {upcoming_holiday_detail_reducer} from '../reducers/upcomingholidaydetails.jsx'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class EventDetails extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Upcoming_HolidayList: []
            };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.props.upcoming_holiday_details();
        this.setState({Upcoming_HolidayList:this.props.upcoming_holiday_details()})

    }


    render()
    {
      /* The data from reducer is objects of objects type and so the conversion into array of objects an dpassing into
     components  for processing.
     */
            /* the id from upcoming holidays page passed here to view it */
            **var id ={this.props.params.click_id} ;
            console.log(id ,'id in event detailssssssssssssss');**

        }
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="margin">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="main_content">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                        <div className="panel panel-info">
                                            <div className="panel-heading">
                                                <div className="panel-title">
                                                    <strong>Event Details</strong><span className="pull-right"><Link to='/userdashboard/home' className="view-all-front btn btn-default">Go Back</Link></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="panel-body form-horizontal">
                                                <div className="col-md-12 notice-details-margin">
                                                    <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                                        <label className="control-label"><strong>Title:</strong></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                                                        <p className="form-control-static">Tamil New Year</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-md-12 notice-details-margin">
                                                    <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                                        <label className="control-label"><strong>Description:</strong></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                                                        <p className="form-control-static text-justify">Tamil New Year</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-md-12 notice-details-margin">
                                                    <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                                        <label className="control-label"><strong>Start Date:</strong></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                                                        <p className="form-control-static"><span className="text-success">14 Apr 2017</span></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-md-12 notice-details-margin">
                                                    <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                                        <label className="control-label"><strong>End Date:</strong></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                                                        <p className="form-control-static"><span className="text-danger">14 Apr 2017</span></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EventDetails;
```

In table list jsx,we have the link path and i highlighted in bold as I have included the params and trying to get that id of click event in another component which i am trying in console.But i am not getting the id,and i dont know the mistake as i have tried this so far.

Thanks in advance;

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my code.Please have a look and help me

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question right, you're wondering how to pass the context of a nested button out to redux? Below is a simple example of how you could send back button props or the index of the button back to a redux function:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            listOfButtonContext = [{id: 'btn1'}, {id: 'btn2'}],
            callbackToRedux = (btnContext)=> {
                console.log(btnContext)
            }
        } = this.props

        return (<table>
            {
                listOfButtonContext
                    .map((btnContext, btnIdx)=><button onClick={()=>{callbackToRedux(btnContext)}}>{btnContext.id}</button>)
            }
        </table>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change your routes to `<Route path="/userdashboard/eventdetails/:holidayId" />`
and in your `TableList.jsx` change `Link` to

```
<Link to={`/userdashboard/eventdetails/${holiday.id}`} className="calendardetails" onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

it will pass user `holidayId` as part of params. so you can access it in render method of `CalenderDetails` like `var id ={this.props.params.holidayId} ;`

Comment: in link tag is taking as string {holiday.id } value and so i am trying in many possible ways.nothing worked.!!

Comment: As the above code is not allowing to compile using webpack and i am using webpack @1.14.0 version

Comment: How we can pass holiday id in router path as like in link tag??.please help me